# How can I create and wrap the child node around all other child nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have something like this:

```
<DataTable>
   <Tests>
       <Test1>1</Test1>
       <Test2>2</Test2>
       <Test3>3</Test3>
    </Tests>
    <Tests>
       <Test1>4</Test1>
       <Test2>5</Test2>
       <Test3>6</Test3>
    </Tests>
</DataTable>
```

Is there any way to create another child node and wrap it around all other tests like this:

```
  <DataTable>
       <WrapChild>
           <Tests>
               <Test1>1</Test1>
               <Test2>2</Test2>
               <Test3>3</Test3>
            </Tests>
       </WrapChild>
       <WrapChild>
            <Tests>
               <Test1>4</Test1>
               <Test2>5</Test2>
               <Test3>6</Test3>
            </Tests>
      </WrapChild>
 </DataTable>
```

I've created a child WrapChild and now have something like this:

```
<DataTable>
           <WrapChild/>
           <Tests>
             <Test1>1</Test1>
             <Test2>2</Test2>
             <Test3>3</Test3>
           </Tests>
           <Tests>
             <Test1>4</Test1>
             <Test2>5</Test2>
             <Test3>6</Test3>
           </Tests>
</DataTable>
```

My code that creates the child Element is:

```
XmlDocument docForList = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement childElement = docForList.CreateElement("WrapChild");
XmlNode parentNode = docForList.SelectSingleNode("DataTable");
parentNode.InsertBefore(childElement,parentNode.FirstChild);
```

But how can I set it to wrap everything in Tests?

Comment: You just did, so yes!

Comment: Hey @itsme86, just edited my question.. sorry about how poorly it was written before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the "WrapChild" element, you need to append the "Tests" to it as a child.

Sample input:

```
<DataTable>
   <Tests>
       <Test1>1</Test1>
       <Test2>2</Test2>
       <Test3>3</Test3>
    </Tests>
    <Tests>
       <Test1>4</Test1>
       <Test2>5</Test2>
       <Test3>6</Test3>
    </Tests>
</DataTable>
```

Code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var wrap = doc.CreateElement("WrapChild");           
doc.SelectSingleNode("DataTable").AppendChild(wrap);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Tests");
var nodesCount = nodes.Count;
for(var i=0;i<nodesCount;i++)
    wrap.AppendChild(nodes[i]);
```

Output:

```
<DataTable>
    <WrapChild>
        <Tests>
            <Test1>1</Test1>
            <Test2>2</Test2>
            <Test3>3</Test3>
        </Tests>
        <Tests>
            <Test1>4</Test1>
            <Test2>5</Test2>
            <Test3>6</Test3>
        </Tests>
    </WrapChild>
</DataTable>
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that but I just edited my post. Your code works, however it only added it to the second part and not the first part. So the first part is missing WrapChild, but the second half of the XML is successful.

Comment: Adding a loop for some reason will wrap the entire section in WrapChild resulting in One WrapChild.. any suggestions?